# Why is my multithreading code slower than the serial version and what can I do to speed it up?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++20

I've recently learnt the basics of threading and throught i'd take it for a spin. However doing some tests, it seems that the threadded version of the code is actually slower than the serial code. Can anybody spot any problems with the following program? If there are none (highly doubtful) can you propose a strategy where I do observe speed ups. The other thing that crossed my mind is that this is a simple problem, so maybe the overhead incurred by threading isn't worth the effort. In reality the `BealeFunction` below will be a system of ODE's, so computational expensive to evaluate.

Here are the results:

```
    /**
     * Results
     * -------
     *
     * In serial: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 4085 microseonds
     * In serial: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 3606 microseonds
     * In serial: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 4288 microseonds
     *
     * With threading: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 16893 microseonds
     * With threading: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 14333 microseonds
     * With threading: fitness = 163.179; computation took: 13636 microseonds
     *
     */
```

And the code to generate them:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

double BealeFunction(double *parameters) {
    double x = parameters[0];
    double y = parameters[1];
    double first = pow(1.5 - x + x * y, 2);
    double second = pow(2.25 - x + x * pow(y, 2), 2);
    double third = pow(2.625 - x + x * pow(y, 3), 2);
    return first + second + third;
};

double inSerial(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix){
    double total = 0;
    for (auto & i : matrix){
        total += BealeFunction(i.data());
    }
    return total;
}

double withThreading(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix){
    double total = 0;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::vector<std::shared_future<double>> futures;

    auto compute1 = [&](int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
            sum += BealeFunction(matrix[i].data());
        }
        return sum;
    };

    // deal with situation where population size < hardware_concurrency.
    int numThreads = 0;
    if (matrix.size() < (int) std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1) {
        numThreads = matrix.size() - 1; // account for 0 index
    } else {
        numThreads = (int) std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1; // account for main thread
    }
    int numPerThread = floor(matrix.size() / numThreads);
    int remainder = matrix.size() % numThreads;

    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = numPerThread;

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        if (i < remainder) {
            // we need to add one more job for these threads
            startIndex = i * (numPerThread + 1);
            endIndex = startIndex + numPerThread;
        } else {
            startIndex = i * numPerThread + remainder;
            endIndex = startIndex + (numPerThread - 1);
        }
        std::cout << "thread " << i << "; start index: " << startIndex << "; end index:  " << endIndex << std::endl;
        std::shared_future<double> f = std::async(std::launch::async, compute1, startIndex, endIndex);
        futures.push_back(f);
    }

    // now collect the results from futures
    for (auto &future : futures) {
        total += future.get();

    }
    return total;
}

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int N = 2000;
    int M = 2;

    // (setup code)
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(N, std::vector<double>(M));
    int seed = 5;
    std::default_random_engine e(seed);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist1(2.9, 3.1);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist2(0.4, 0.6);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            matrix[i][0] = dist1(e);
            matrix[i][1] = dist2(e);
        }
    }

    double total = withThreading(matrix);
    // double total = inSerial(matrix);


    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "fitness: " << total << std::endl;
    std::cout << "computation took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
              << " microseonds" << std::endl;



}
```

Comment: 2000 rows isn't a large data set.  If you are using 4 threads, that's only 500 iterations each.  The cost of spinning up  the threads could far exceed that.  Try a data set with a few hundred thousand rows.  Also, from just a performance standpoint, a `std::vector<std::aray<double, 2>>` would be a better data structure here.

Comment: Not to mention that it's probably a good idea NOT to create a large matrix, and then immediately making a completely useless duplicate copy of that matrix by the virtue of passing it by value to another function.

Comment: A basic you clearly haven't understood about threading is that there is no free lunch. There is overhead of the threads themselves, so total resource usage (CPU time, memory usage) aggregated from start to finish is more than is the case with single threaded. Threading can offer advantages with concurrent executition IF the algorithm can be split that way and there are multiple cores/processors, so observed time CAN BE less than total processing time. Synchronisation (where threads are required to wait on actions being completed by other threads) offsets that.

Comment: Okay. Using a vector of arrays was a good suggestion and sped computation considerably. I also fixed the pass by ref typo. With `N=1e7` I get about a 1.3 to 1.5 times speedup using 11 threads. I knew that threading incurs overhead, but I'm not experienced enough to know *how much* speed up can be expected. It seems x1.3 to x1.5 with 11 threads is a poor effort though.

Comment: There is no guarantee that each thread will run on a separate core.  Worst case, your threads will be scheduled along with all the other tasks running on a single core.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, since C++11, there are ways to make things a bit more explicit and controllable here: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/

Comment: _I get about a 1.3 to 1.5 times speedup using 11 threads_ What made you choose 11 threads?  How many cores do you have?

Comment: @PaulSanders This is `std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1` on my laptop.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh: If you want performances, avoid creating the threads every time you launch a function. You can detach 8 threads and store 8 condition_variable in an array to wait for their destruction at the end of everything. This way, every time you want to compute something, just share a condition_variable between them and the task producer to notify them to compute something. Even with this method, this is maybe not as good as a for loop with #pragma omp parallel for => you should check this feature !

Comment: @Cevik Appreciate the advice, thanks.